# Strengthened version of Taylor's theorem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $[a,b]$ that is $n+1$
>   times differentiable on $(a,b)$ and such that $f^{(1)},
>  f^{(2)},\ldots,f^{(n+1)}$ are bounded on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  a}f^{(1)}(x)$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  a}f^{(2)}(x),\ldots$ exist. Prove that:
>
> $$f(b)=f(a)+\lim_{x\rightarrow
> > a}f^{(1)}(x)\frac{(b-a)}{1!}+\lim_{x\rightarrow
> > a}f^{(2)}(x)\frac{(b-a)^2}{2!}+\ldots+f^{(n+1)}(c)\frac{(b-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
>
> where $c$ is between $a$ and $b$.

I know how to prove "the standard" version of Taylor's theorem. But here I don't know how to start. Any hint please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all we show that the limits of the derivatives at the extremes of the interval exist. Let $1\le j\le n$. Since $f^{(j+1)}$ is bounded, $f^{(j)}$ is uniformly continuous. It follows that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f^{(j)}(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f^{(j)}(x)$ exist.

The existence of the above limits imply that the lateral derivatives of $f$ at $a$ and $b$ exist up to order $n$, and are equal to those limits.

Now you can apply Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't see how can I now apply Taylor's theorem.

Comment: $f$ and its derivatives up to order $n$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, and the $n+1$-th derivative exists in $(a,b)$. Under these conditions, Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange remainder holds.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm only familiar with this version of Taylor's theorem: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/taylors_thm/

Comment: The person I refer to is a generalization of the mean value theorem, which corresponds to $n=1$. This is the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).